# Order of $Z^1(G,A)$, the group of $1$-cocycles, when both $G$ and $A$ are finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

I was reading about first cohomology group [$H^1(G,A)$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/First_cohomology_group) for a group $G$ acting on an abelian group $A$. As one can see from the definition, $H^1(G,A)=Z^1(G,A)/B^1(G,A)$ where [$Z^1(G,A)$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/1-cocycle_for_a_group_action) is the group of $1$-cocycles. I am actually curious about the order of the group $Z^1(G,A)$. My question is

> How the order of $Z^1(G,A)$ depends on order of $G$ and $A$ when both $G$ and $A$ are finite?

I am not familiar with many results about this topic. I am really sorry. Any help about the question will be greatly appreciated. If there is any reference/result even for special class of groups, say $p$-groups, I will be interested to know also.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. It seems a bit like "Let $G$ be a finite group. What is the order of $G$?". What sort of answer are you expecting?

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, I am sorry. My question is poorly phrased. I am looking for some result which says how the order of $Z^1(G,A)$ depends on order of $G$ and $A$. Sorry. I will edit the post also.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the comment, I edited the post. If still I am missing something, pls feel free to comment.

Comment: I don't think that's only about the order of $G,A$. It also depends on the action of $G$ on $A$. (Think about the case where the action is trivial...)

Comment: The exponent of $Z^1(G,A)$ divides the exponent of $A$. I am not sure if you can say much more than that in general. It depends on the action of $G$ on $A$ so it is not determined just by $G$ and $A$.

Comment: @Yanko Oh, yes, right. I understand.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. Yes the dependence of the action plays a role. So computing in GAP is possibly one option for particular $G$ and $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $G$ and $A$ have coprime order. Then $H^1(G,A)$ is trivial, so has order $1$. For a proof, see my [notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_16_coho_course.pdf), Corollary $2.4.5$. This gives many examples.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. The notes are so useful and many things to learn.